# Python не принимает данные из переменной

Tags: python, web3.py

Делаю отправку BNB из одного кошелька на другой

```
sign_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(token_tx, private_key=private_key)
```

вот на этом моменте выбивает ошибка

```
    return binascii.unhexlify(ascii_hex)
binascii.Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

НО если я ввожу его как бы без переменной

```
sign_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(token_tx, private_key='...')
```

то все хорошо, как мне быть?
Пробовал через f''

Comment: Приведите больше данных. Добавьте в вопрос стек ошибки. Добавьте в метки / вопрос название используемой библиотеки. Пока мало что понятно :)

Comment: А что у вас в `ascii_hex`, непонятно, откуда эта переменная берётся

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, переменная бралась из списка и в конце был знак переноса строки (`\n`).

Убрал его с помощью `line.rstrip('\n')`.